# Make Wordpress installation scalable on OpenShift

Tags: wordpress, openshift, scaling

I followed this link to make my wordpress installation scalable on OpenShift http://gshipley-onpaas.rhcloud.com/scaling-wordpress-on-the-cloud. However, I think I have missed a step somewhere. My git repository does not contain any application wordpress file. I understood that that is the purpose. I only have plugins and themes on the application git. However when the second gear is started (due to scaling), only my files are deployed, not the wordpress installation itself. I must have done something wrong. But I don't understand why it doesn't deploy the wordpress files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the wordpress developer quickstart (https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-wordpress-developer-quickstart) which included the base wordpress installation also, but you will still have to use an s3 plugin for your uploaded files.

Comment: Thx Corey, that's the one I used actually, and I have S3 and cloudfront working. All is fine on the first gear, it's when the second gear spins up. My app repository containing plugins, themes and config is deployed but not the wordpress installation itself. When I execute: git remote add upstream -m master git://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example.git
git pull -s recursive -X theirs upstream master, I get already up to date, but no wordpress installation is deployed to the second gear.

Comment: Do the wordpress installation files show up in your git repo locally?

Comment: No they don't, but I think that's not supposed to be the case if you look in the deploy script:# Replace the php/ directory with provided clean WordPress installation
#
if [ -d ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}php ]; then
  rm -rf ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}php
fi
ln -sf ${dest_dir} ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}php     and  the build script should download the wordpress installation. For some reason this is not happening on the second gear kicking in.